# 'google.colab.files.download' to specific location/directory in PC

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I know that in Colab, using

```
 from google.colab import files
 files.download('sample.txt')
```

downloads the target file into your local /Downloads directory,
but I couldn't find much documentation about how to customize the download directory?
or is there an alternative library I can use in Colab?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I don’t think there will be, since Colab has to go through your browser’s preferences. I usually save files from Colab to my google drive, then sync my drive to a particular folder on my computer.

Comment: Hm, haven't thought of that, I'll give it a try, thanks.